# how to correct a warped document?

Tags: c, image, algorithm, image-processing, scanning

I'm coding a software to dewarp an image.
Example : when you take a photo of a page of a book with a camera , the page is not well shaped like that:
[there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zO8v.jpg)

So the first part of my program change the shape so the final shape is a rectangle (that almost works fine):
[there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPIpc.jpg)

But my problem as you can see, is that at the edge of my photo the texte is smaller in the width that the texte at the middle of the image, so how what algorithm can I apply to correct that??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the way the text lines are morphed it seems that you are using a 2d mapping when in fact you should use 3d mapping.
See the additional reading part in http://www.vision.caltech.edu/savarese/main.htm especially the first one.